# Как взять ip?

Tags: php

Как взяать ip?

```
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ;
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

так не получается

Comment: а почему не получается ? В чем именно причина "не получается" ?

Comment: $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); echo $ip; просто хочу увидеть что в $ip, а потом добавлю в таблицу в базе

Comment: и что же в ip ?

Comment: ну думаю что число

Comment: $ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); так должно быть типа так 2561451964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто вывести ip то делаем так:

```
echo "Ваш ip адрес".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

А если для заноса в бд то пробуйте так:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];// Запоминаем ip
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `бе-бе` (ip) values('$ip')" ) or die(mysql_error()); //Заносим ip
```

Comment: снова не дает ip, а тип ip таблице какую взять?

Comment: varchar конечно-же

Comment: Так написал ip дает ::1

    CREATE TABLE messages(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

    $message = $_POST['messages'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message,ip) VALUES('$message','$ip')");

Comment: Так сделайте: $DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message,ip) VALUES('$message','$ip')") or die(mysql_error()); Что показывает?

Comment: в столбике  ip добавляет ::1

Comment: Сделайте тот же запрос только в бд в разделе SQL

Answer (score 0):

Если не изменяет память

```
   $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

Comment: тоже не получилось:(

Comment: а как вы это определяете? можно ваш код увидеть?(тот кусок по которому вы определяете что не работает)

Comment: $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); 
echo $ip;
просто хочу ужидеть что в $ip, а потом добавлю в таблицу в базе

Comment: тогда не имею ни малейшего понятия, у меня работает без проблем

Comment: спасибо и на этом:)